# Query to Select Existing Key

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table with the following data

```
key     code
============
key1    220
key1    221
key2    220
key2    221
key2    222
key3    220
key4    255
key5    220
key5    221
```

A combination of key and code cannot repeat in the table (the 2 columns are used as composite primary keys).
I will like a query that will select the matching keys for a given set of codes e.g. for codes 220, 221, the expected result will be key1 and key 5 because only these match exactly these code set.

Comment: What have you tried?  If you want to do code-by-request then you should hire a consultant.  Stack Overflow is for assistance with specific issues.

Comment: I think your SQL Server is broken because both your `key3` rows has code `220`.

Comment: @MikaelEriksson Or, possibly, he wants only the keys that have *exactly* 220 *and* 221, which only key1 and key5 match.

Comment: @BertEvans Nah, I'm referring to the fact that the "(the 2 columns are used as composite primary keys)"

Comment: @MikaelEriksson: probably a typo

Comment: @MikaelEriksson: corrected the typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Insert the values you are looking for to a table variable `@Match` and use that in a query against your table `@T`.

```
declare @T table
(
  [key] char(4),
  code int,
  primary key([key], code)
)

insert into @T values
('key1',    220),
('key1',    221),
('key2',    220),
('key2',    221),
('key2',    222),
('key3',    220),
('key3',    333),
('key4',    255),
('key5',    220),
('key5',    221)

declare @Match table (code int)
insert into @Match values (220),(221)

select T.[key]
from @T as T
  left outer join @Match as M
    on T.code = M.code
group by T.[key]
having count(*) = (select count(*) from @Match) and
       count(M.code) = (select count(*) from @Match)
```

https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/119432/

Comment: Doesn't quite work... try adding another key3 row ('key3',333).

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for something like this??

```
DECLARE @Test TABLE (TblKey CHAR(4), code INT)

INSERT INTO @test VALUES('key1', 220),('key1', 221),('key2', 220),('key2', 221),
                        ('key2', 222),('key3', 220),('key3', 220),
                        ('key4', 255),('key5', 220), ('key5', 221)

SELECT TblKey FROM @Test WHERE Code = 220
INTERSECT
SELECT TblKey FROM @Test WHERE Code = 221
```

When I run this, I get an output of `key1, key2, key5` - all of which have an entry with both values 220 and 221 in your sample.

Comment: The result set shouldn't include `key2` because it also has an entry with value `222`...@MikaelEriksson and @BertEvans have the right answers.

Answer (score 1):

Just to throw another option on the table:

```
declare @KeyCode Table
(
    [Key] nvarchar(10),
    Code nvarchar(10)
)

insert into @KeyCode values('key1',    220)
insert into @KeyCode values('key1',    221)
insert into @KeyCode values('key2',    220)
insert into @KeyCode values('key2',    221)
insert into @KeyCode values('key2',    222)
insert into @KeyCode values('key3',    220)
insert into @KeyCode values('key3',    220)
insert into @KeyCode values('key4',    255)
insert into @KeyCode values('key5',    220)
insert into @KeyCode values('key5',    221)

select [Key]
from @KeyCode
where Code = 220

intersect

select [Key]
from @KeyCode
where Code = 221

except 

select [Key]
from @KeyCode
where Code not in (220,221)
```

Returns key1 and key5.

[Working example.](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/119400/)

Comment: +1...simple and easy to understand, using set arithmetic. I wish I could upvote twice for the StackExchange Data Explorer link :)

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this?

```
SELECT key 
FROM tblKeyCodes 
where code in (220,221)
```